# Creating/using dynamic values across templates

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify3 and have a table with many templates that each need access to additional information based on the item.  Below is a super-simple example with the most relevant parts shown

```
<template>
  <v-data-table v-model:="someModel" :headers="someHeader" :items="someData"
   item-value="name">

    <template #item.calories="{ item }">
     <span v-if="gatherAdditionalData(item).someValue">BLAH</span>
     <span v-else-if="gatherAdditionalData(item).someOtherValue">Foo</span>
    </template>

    <template #item.protein="{ item }">
     <span v-if="gatherAdditionalData(item).someValue">BLAH</span>
     <span v-else-if="gatherAdditionalData(item).someOtherValueAgain">Bar</span>
    </template>

  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script setup>
const someData: [{
  name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
  calories: 159,
  fat: 6.0,
  carbs: 24,
  protein: 4.0,
  iron: '1',
 }]

function gatherAdditionalData(item) {
 return someDataCreatedBasedOnItem;
}
</script>
```

It seems there should be an easier way than calling the gatherAdditionalData function multiple times for each separate template and within each template.  Is there a way to get the current table row, call gatherAdditionalData one time and inject that into each template?

My best guess is to make a computed value that that takes someData and merges it with additionalInfo and the use that computed value instead of someData

Thanks

Comment: Your best guess sounds like the typical way of doing it.  Format/fetch all the additional data, merge it with your initial data, then bind the result to the v-data-table

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks